# How to share data using Content Provider in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing an application in which I want to share my application data with another using `ContentProvider`.

But not getting proper solution. Can any one help me? Is there any good tutorial regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of data you want to share between application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to create your content provider

here is the tutorial:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

then to fetch the results from content provider, you need to create a class in another application that extends content resolver and call the query used in content provider.